# JAXB -field based on two sibling XML elements

Tags: jaxb

for example  i have this xml:

```
<xml>
  <a>1</a>
  <b>2</b>
</xml>
```

and this class:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "xml")
public class xml{

int aPlusb;
....
}
```

i know how to create an XmlAdapter but i would like it to set the filed aPlusb to be the plus between the value of element a and the value of filed b.

is there a way to do this in JAXB without making an XmlTransient field and calculate it separately?

Comment: You may find the following helpful:  http://blog.bdoughan.com/2010/08/xmltransformation-going-beyond.html